# Dynamic Function Call PHP

Tags: php, variables, dynamic

I have a very specific question: is the following code possible in one line? Or is there a beter way to do the same?

```
$key = rand(1,100);

$temp = 'GetObjects'.ucfirst($key).'Array';
$objects = $this->module->$temp();
```

Like this:

```
$objects = $this->module->'GetObjects'.ucfirst($key).'Array'();
```

Comment: Honestly, you have that many methods on your `module` that 1-100 works?  Good god!

Comment: No, $key is an example it has 1-20 methods or so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe

```
$objects = $this->module->{'GetObjects'.ucfirst($key).'Array'}();
```

or

```
$objects = call_user_func(array($this->module, 'GetObjects'.ucfirst($key).'Array'));
```